# Where do I put files other than build.gradle?

Tags: gradle

So what is the standard / best practice for files like custom tasks or scripts? Where do I put them? I would rather not have them all in the project root and it is highly unlikely that I would be permitted to create a new stand-alone project in git. (I will ask though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a whole chapter on this in the [user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html). There are a number of ways to split up and organize build logic, but the simplest way to decompose a complex build script is via [script plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:configuring_using_external_script).

Comment: buildSrc turns out to be the answer I was looking for. :-) Missed it on the first two passes through the docs. Guess I ought to slow down.